# This code is running in 3.4 but errors in 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have coded an algorithm for the secant method. Code is running fine in 3.4 but in 2.7 it gives error of `str` and `float` concatenation. However, by using `str` function it does not give the error of concatenation but it gives error of `float` division.

```
import random
import math
def secant(x, y, f):
    count_iterations = 0
    negligible_val = 0.000001
    while abs(f(y)) > negligible_val:
        z = x - ((y - x)/(f(y) - f(x))) * f(x)
        x = y
        y = z
        count_iterations += 1
    return y
x,y = random.uniform(0.1, 10.0), random.uniform(0.1, -10.0)
= input("Enter the function in brackets to find the roots: ")
#remember to put the input in the brackets
#example (x**3-x-11)
pars_text = "lambda x: " + str(input_func)
result = eval(pars_text)
roots = str(secant(x, y, result))
print("Roots are: " + roots)
```

Comment: It is not possible your code runs in both, `input` does two very different things in both, `/` also behaves differently in both

Comment: @PadraicCunningham what means brother? how to change it in 2.7?

Comment: `from __future__ import division` and use `raw_input`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i know about raw inpu tbut what is from_future_import division?

Comment: It won't floor i.e 4/3 = 1.333.... not 1

Comment: _future_ is a package that supports Python 3 features in Python 2 code.  You would want to import the **division** operator to be consistent.

Comment: @Prune so i just need to add from_future_import division in my code?

Comment: @programmer, did you use `from __future__ import division` and `raw_input` because of you did you would see the code works, you cannot use `input` as I already told you

Comment: That will fix the division functionality.  You still need to handle the input() difference.  I think that you can make that **import division, input** and fix them both.

Comment: yeah brother @Prune and this code working thankx again guys

Comment: yes it is working thankx again both of you